# UILabel Strikethrough

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uilabel

Is it possible to `stikethrough` a `UILabel` at all?  I can't seem to find the option...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an old question and newer information is available.

Starting in iOS 6, we have [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

For pre iOS 6, I would look at [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel)

Answer (score 4):

You could create another UILabel above your label and use an en dash character:

```
label.text = @"––––––––––––––––––";
```

Caveat: works with Helvetica (system default).  It may not work with other fonts.

Answer (score 3):

iPhone doesn't support attributed strings (which is usually the way you'd do this in Cocoa), so I don't believe it's possible.

You could subclass `UILabel` and draw the `strikethrough` yourself.  I've also seen some people use a `UIWebView` to do this type of thing, but that seems like overkill to me.

Comment: Thanks, bit rubbish though!  blimin Apple!

Comment: Starting iOS 6, it does support NSAttributedString. See my post

Answer (score 1):

```
UIView* slabel = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x, label.frame.origin.y+10, label.frame.size.width, 2)];
[self addSubview:slabel];
[slabel setBackgroundColor:label.textColor];
```

You can add a view over UILabel and style it with label properties.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSAttributedString *str=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]  initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"¥%.2f", productOne.priceBefore]  attributes:@{NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)}];

cell.priceBefore.attributedText = str;
```